# Not able to copy time variable in new file

Tags: python, python-3.x

### i have one NetCDF file i did some modification in lat and lon but time variable variable want to keep same. how to copy the time variable in one file to another. Thanks in advance

```
from netCDF4 import num2date, date2num, date2index , Dataset
import glob


root_grp = nc.Dataset('EXP_2A_25_newcor.nc', 'w',format="NETCDF3_CLASSIC")

file1 = glob.glob('EXP_2A_25_out.nc')
for i, datafile in enumerate(file1):
 data = Dataset(datafile, 'r')
 lat=np.array(data.variables['lat'])
 lon= np.array(data.variables['lon'])
 times= data.variables['time']
  pcp= data.variables['max_dbz']

  nlat = len(lat) # Size of the matrix ndim*ndim
  nlon = len(lon) # Size of the matrix ndim*ndim
  ntime = len(times) # Size of the matrix ndim*ndim

root_grp.createDimension('t', ntime)
root_grp.createDimension('x', nlat)
root_grp.createDimension('y', nlon)

time = root_grp.createVariable('t', 'f8', ('t',))
x = root_grp.createVariable('x', 'f4', ('x',))
y = root_grp.createVariable('y', 'f4', ('y',))
dbz = root_grp.createVariable('dbz', 'f8', ('t', 'x', 'y',))

x_range =  np.linspace(-6, 6, nlat)
y_range =  np.linspace(-6, 6, nlon)
x[:] = x_range
y[:] = y_range
for i in range(ntime):
 time[i] = times[i]
 dbz[i,:,:] = pcp[i,:,:]
root_grp.close()
```

Comment: What difference are you seeing? Are you saying the code throws an error? If so, please show the error.

Comment: No Sir, I am not able to understand when to use this two type of array in which situation. I want time series plot from this data in (temp) variable ['tc'] is 4D.

Comment: The project pages says that *xarray (formerly xray) is an open source project and Python package that aims to bring the labeled data power of pandas to the physical sciences, by providing N-dimensional variants of the core pandas data structures*. IMHO it means that the difference is that xarray mixes pandas and numpy features. ([ref.](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/))

Comment: Sorry to see no-one posted an answer. I asked a related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54698146/whats-the-difference-between-numpys-structured-arrays-vs-xarray-xray maybe we can get an answer